# How to get all the records in mongodb having object id

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

In the mongodb there is a user data has been stored in collection `challange` the data seems like bellow:

```
{
"_id" : 1,
 "name" : "puneet",
 "last" : "jindal",
 "email" : "puneet@g.com"
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b3af82cdb3aaa47792b5fd3"),
 "name" : "hardeep",
 "last" : "singh",
 "email" : "hardeep@g.com"
}
{ 
 "_id" : 3,
 "name" : "gaurav",
 "last" : "bansal",
 "email" : "gaurav@g.com"
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b3af87ddb3aaa47792b5fd4"),
 "name" : "manish",
 "last" : "jindal",
 "email" : "manish@g.com"
}
```

In the above data there are four records and two of them having id in the integer form and other will having id in object form. I just want to retrieve the all the records which are having the `object id` in the id field. can anyone tell what query should I write in the code that will only retrieve that records which are having the object id.

Updated:

code I'm using :

```
type User struct {
 Id              bson.ObjectId    `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
 Name            string    `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
 Last            string `json:"last,omitempty" bson:"last,omitempty"`
 Email          string `json:"email,omitempty" bson:"email,omitempty"`
}
type Users []User

func GetAllUsers(listQuery interface{}) (result Users, err error) {
 mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()
 sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
 defer sessionCopy.Close()
 getCollection := mongoSession.DB(config.Database).C(config.UsersCollection)
 err = getCollection.Find(listQuery).Select(bson.M{"password": 0}).All(&result)
 if err != nil {
    return result, err
 }
 return result, nil
}

conditions := bson.M{'_id': bson.M{'$type': "objectId" } }
data, err := models.GetAllUsers(conditions)
```

The error I'm facing by using this :-

> controllers/UserController.go:18:23: invalid character literal (more than one character)
>   controllers/UserController.go:18:28: cannot use '\u0000' (type rune) as type string in map key

Comment: No. I've never used MongoDB. I don't know why you assume that someone who improves your formatting would be a subject matter expert on your specific question. But you already have multiple answers.

Comment: @flimzy these answers are right if we run this in the mongodb shell but i need it to make as a query in golang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'_id'` and `'$type'` are invalid [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals), you can't list multiple runes (characters) in a rune literal (only a single rune).

The [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#M) type is a map with `string` key type, so you have to use [string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) (or expressions), like this:

```
conditions := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$type": "objectId"}}
```

Also note that the [`bson`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson) package holds [constants](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#pkg-constants) for the different types, so it's safer to use those constants:

```
conditions := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$type": bson.ElementObjectId}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator:

```
db.challenge.find({ _id: { $type: "objectId" } })
```

Comment: then how it will written in go can you tell me sir @mickl

Comment: @ansh there was nothing about go in your question :) You need to read the docs, maybe here: https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Find

Comment: see I'm using the Query like that `
 conditions := bson.M{'_id': bson.M{'$type': "objectId" } }

 data, err := models.GetAllUsers(conditions)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
//For Retrieving for ObjectID
db.challange.find(
    {
        "_id": {
            $type: 7  //ObjectID
        }
    }
)

//For Retrieving for Number
db.challange.find(
    {
        $or: [
            {
                "_id": {
                    $type: 1  //double
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    $type: 16  //32 bit integer
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    $type: 18  //64 bit integer
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    $type: 19  //decimal
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Refer [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) ,  [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Comment: can you please tell me how i will write the query in go lang

Comment: refer this document http://goinbigdata.com/how-to-build-microservice-with-mongodb-in-golang/

Comment: see @ratanUdayKumar I'm also writing it like that but it gives me error`conditions := bson.M{'_id': bson.M{'$type': "objectId" } }
 data, err := models.GetAllUsers(conditions)`